# Let $N_t$ be a $PP(3)$. Let $T_n$ be the time of the nth arrival. Find $E(N_5|N_2 = 5)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, poisson-process

Let $N_t$ be a $PP(3)$. Let $T_n$ be the time of the nth arrival. Find:

> 1. $\Bbb E\left(N_5\mid N_2 = 5\right)$
> 2. $\Bbb E\left(T_9\mid N_2 = 5\right)$

**My effort**:

1. $\Bbb E\left(N_5\mid N_2 = 5\right)=\Bbb E(N_3)+5=\Bbb E(N_1+N_1+N_1)+5=1/3+1/3+1/3+5$ and
2. $\Bbb E\left(T_9\mid N_2 = 5\right)=\Bbb E(T_4+5)=4\times 1/3 +5?$

Is this correct?

Comment: I think the second has to be $+2$ not $+5$ because $T_9$ corresponds to time not to number of arrivals, correct?

Comment: yes, that's true. Thanks a lot

Comment: Usually $PP(\lambda)$ means PP with rate/intensity $\lambda$, hence $E(N_3)=3\cdot 3$.

Comment: thanks, so you can't split the $N_t$? I thought that since the times are independent, the number of events at $t=3$ is the sum of events $t=1$ 3 times

Comment: You can. $E(N_1)=3$.

Comment: My notes say with an exponentialy distributed $\lambda $ rate the expected lifetime is $1/ \lambda$

Comment: ...And your notes are right: if the expected lifetime is $1/\lambda$ then $E(N_t)=\lambda t$. **Take-home checking procedure:** Assume that a large number $n$ of events occurred, then each event takes an amount of time $1/\lambda$ on average, hence their sum takes an amount of time of the order of $n/\lambda$, that is, if $t\approx n/\lambda$ then $N_t\approx n$, thus, $N_t\approx \lambda t$. This law-of-large-numbers-type argument does not show the identity $E(N_t)=\lambda t$ for every $t$ but it can help discriminate between a $\lambda$ prefactor and a $1/\lambda$ prefactor.

Comment: Expected time per one arrival (i.e. between arrivals) is $\frac 1 \lambda$. Expected number of arrivals per unit of time is $\lambda$.